# Yahoo Finance API Java Download CSV

Tags: java, url, inputstream, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I have been using the Yahoo Finance "API" with the code below for a few weeks.  Since about a week ago, it stopped working.  If you type in this address: http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=MSFT, you'll get some historical data for Microsoft (my browser automatically downloads it).  However, when I try to read it through Java, the stream is apparently opened (I don't get an exception), however, the stream contains no data.  Anyone know why the buffered reader below is not able to stream the object as it had been able to do in previous weeks?  I suspect that maybe Yahoo added some java script to block automated downloading.

```
URL url = new URL("http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" + symbol);
URLConnection hc = url.openConnection();
hc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 4.10; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(hc.getInputStream()));
    br.readLine();
    //Read File Line By Line
    String strLine;
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(strLine);
    }
    br.close();
```

Comment: May I suggest you use a tool such as Wireshark to see the actual communication between you and Yahoo!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the URL from "http" to "https" which works without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Many Websites are checking for a User Agent String and block acess if no String has been sent to block automated access.

This is an example how you can add the user agent string:

```
    URL url = new URL("http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=MSFT");
    URLConnection hc = url.openConnection();
    hc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 4.10; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0");
```

Comment: Thanks tak3shi, I edited the original post to include your suggestion, but the stream reader is still empty.

Answer (score 1):

To understand the reason the java communication doesn't work, track the html communication.  I used Chrome browser, with HTTP trace extension enabled.  The trace output shows that the link
http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=^GSPC
redirects to 
https://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=^GSPC.

In Java, you need to implement a URL connection to follow the redirect.  An example of following the redirect is at http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-httpurlconnection-follow-redirect-example/.  Modify the example by passing your url string, and you should get the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

1. This is a java code to download the historical stocks data from yahoo finance.
2. here I have taken the required date parameters and set them in a Calender Object, then this object is converted to period object  this object is passed to the function where it will be converted to UNIX timestamp and then that value is appended to the link
3. I have created a url object and that will get the csv file of the historical data for the required ticker value which is read using the input stream reader and them it is displayed on the console.

   ```
    public class demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {

    final String SYM = "TSLA";
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2019);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JULY);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 16);

    Date period1 = datechange(cal);
    cal1.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2019);
    cal1.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JULY);
    cal1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 23);
    Date period2 = datechange(cal1);

    String interval="1d";

    long strDate = (period1.getTime());
    strDate= strDate/1000;
    long strDate1 = (period2.getTime());
    strDate1= strDate1/1000;
    //System.out.println(strDate+" "+strDate1+"     ans");
    String link="https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/"+SYM+"?period1="+strDate+"&period2="+strDate1+"&interval="+interval+"&events=history";

    URL url = new URL(link);
    URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
    InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(inStream);


    String line =buf.readLine();
    while(line != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        line=buf.readLine();
    }
    }

    public static Date datechange(Calendar cal) throws ParseException {
    Date dateOne =cal.getTime();
    //boolean date1904 = true;
    //double ans =DateUtil.getExcelDate(cal,date1904);

    String a = dateOne.toString();
    String b[] = a.split(" ");
    String c = b[1]+" "+b[2]+" "+b[5];
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy", 
    Locale.ENGLISH);
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    cal.setTime(sdf.parse(c));
    dateOne=cal.getTime();
    sdf.format(dateOne);
    return dateOne;

    }


    }
   ```

Comment: Some explanation of why this is a good solution should  be added to your answer using [edit]. Code only answers do not always help readers understand why this might be the best solution, so you need to explain more.

Answer (score 1):

There is yahoofinance library

```
implementation group: 'com.yahoofinance-api', name: 'YahooFinanceAPI', version: '3.17.0'
```

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

import yahoofinance.Stock;
import yahoofinance.YahooFinance;
import yahoofinance.histquotes.HistoricalQuote;
import yahoofinance.histquotes.Interval;

public class GetQuotes {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Calendar from = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar to = Calendar.getInstance();
        from.add(Calendar.YEAR, -5); // from 5 years ago
         
        Stock google = YahooFinance.get("ENB.TO");
        List<HistoricalQuote> data = google.getHistory(from, to, Interval.DAILY);
        
        data.forEach(t -> { 
            System.out.println(t.getOpen() + "  " + t.getClose());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Try executing this code from some other network. That'll give you clarity whether Yahoo has blocked automated downloading or only blacklisted the network you're using.

Comment: Have you read in the question that it works from the browser?